# How to stop Apache maven <outputDirectory> to overwrite the folder

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3

I have the following directory hierarchy:

```
generated 

   |    
   | -->java
```

Java directory has the following package: **com.model**

that contains java models that I copy/paste from somewhere before I compile the application.

The issue that I use Protocol buffer and I tell maven to output the generated files on same previous directory BUT over a new package:

Result : Protocol buffer generates  the new package and deletes the old package.
I have no idea why does it do that although the package names are different?

Here is that part of pom I use to generate java from protocol buffer:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <protocExecutable>C:\protoc.exe</protocExecutable>
                <protoSourceRoot>./src/proto</protoSourceRoot>
                <outputDirectory>./src/generated/java</outputDirectory>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look at the code for the plugin you'll see that the code has been hardcoded to clean the directory:

https://github.com/dtrott/maven-protoc-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/maven/AbstractProtocMojo.java#L154

```
// Quick fix to fix issues with two mvn installs in a row (ie no clean)
cleanDirectory(outputDirectory);
```

There's 2 ways to solve this..either set the output directory to a temp directory and then use the maven copy plugin or the maven build plugin to copy the files into the directory of your choice, or modify the maven plugin to remove that line (or better yet make it configurable).

Tommy

Comment: Actually ur first approach is what I was afraid to mention as I have been trying ,but not hard enough, to move the generated directory to the prefered location. Howeever so far is not so promising ..... could  u have some hints u may share with me that makes me cut/paste the directory to the new location using maven !

Comment: Have a look at the usage for the copy-resources goal: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html      just make sure to turn filtering off in this case

Comment: I've used "maven-antrun-plugin" but I get the "An Ant BuildException has occured: Only one of tofile and todir may be set"...please review my answer below .I was wondering if u can assist me into that !

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue by the following :

```
<plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>run</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <tasks>
                              <delete dir="./destination"/>
                              <copy todir="./destination">
                                    <fileset dir="./source"/>
                              </copy>
                              <delete dir="./source"/>
                          </tasks>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However , I get this error "An Ant BuildException has occured: Only one of tofile and todir may be set"

Comment: Actually , I have found this at the source code :
if (destFile != null && destDir != null) {
            throw new BuildException("Only one of tofile and todir "
                                     + "may be set.");
        }
  However, I have already created both the destination directories !!